# Adding navigation bar and footer

Tags: tex4ht

I would like to incorporate tex4ht output into an existing web page. I'm wondering if there is a neat way to put the navigation bar and footer of said web page into every HTML file generated with tex4ht.

For example: can you tell tex4ht via a .cfg file to put certain HTML code at the beginning/end of the `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\Configure{BODY}{insert <body>}{insert </body>}` configuration. Example:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{BODY}          
   {\SaveEndP\IgnorePar 
       \HCode{\Hnewline<body \csname a:!BODY\endcsname
     >%
     <div class="header"><p>This is a header</p></div>
     }\ShowPar\par}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{%
   \Hnewline<div class="footer"><p>This is a footer</p></div>\Hnewline
   \Hnewline</body>}
   \RecallEndP}%
\EndPreamble
```

There is some business related to paragraph handling involved, but what is important for your use case are `\HCode` commands, which are used to include `HTML` tags. You can also put text here, to insert line break, use `\Hnewline` command.

There is one issue with `\HCode`, you can't accented letters inside it's argument, it is best to use it only for tags including.

Sample document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head> <title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- charset=utf-8,html,xhtml --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
</head> 
<body ><div class="header"><p>This is a header</p></div> 
<!--l. 3--><p class="noindent" >hello world </p> 
<div class="footer"><p>This is a footer</p></div> 

</body> </html>
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you. Just one further question: if I use the german umlaut `ä` in the header/footer, it's replaced by `\protect \let \prOteCt \relax \Protect \csname acp:c\endcsname {23}a` (similiarly for `ö` and `ü`). Putting umlauts in your MWE doesn't result in the same problem, so it must be something in my current setup. Do you have a suggestion where I should start searching the culprit?

Comment: @Adrian try to move the accented letters outside the `\HCode` command.